# How to print the values pointed by an array of void pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, void

**I have defined a structure to hold a group of values of any type, that's why the void **data. I would really appreciate if someone helps me in how to print the values pointer by an array of void pointers.**

Here is the structure.

```
typedef struct item{
   void **data;//array of void pointer to store names of the group-members
   int count;//number of members in the group
   struct item *next; //pointer to the next group in the pool queue
} group;
```

Now, let say a group is created as follows:

```
group *gp = (group*) malloc(sizeof(group));
void *a[2];
a[0] = (void*) "John";
a[1] = (void*) "Jim";
gp->data = a;
gp->count = 2;
```

At some point, probably inside another function, if I need to print the array of values of a group node, what code should I write? Here is such a function:

```
void print_group_node(group *gp)
{
   //I have the check for vp==NULL here
   void **vp = gp->data;
   int c = gp->count;
   int i;
   for(i = 0; i < c; i++)
      printf();//what should I write here
   //other codes here
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: `printf("%s \n", (char *)vp[i])`

Answer (score 2):

If the data could be any type of variable. You probably need one more field similar to `data_type` below in the structure `group` to tell what type `data` has.

```
typedef struct item{
   ....
   int data_type; // 0: int, 1: char * (string), ...
} group;
```

And use appropriate `printf()` as per it.

```
void print_group_node(group *gp)
{
   //I have the check for vp==NULL here
   void **vp = gp->data;
   int c = gp->count;
   int i;
   for(i = 0; i < c; i++)
   switch (gp->data_type) {
      case 0:
           printf("%d \n", (int*)vp[i])
           break;
      case 1:
           printf("%s \n", (char *)vp[i])
           break;
      Default:
           printf("Unknown type");
           break;
    }
}
```

As currently your data points to strings `printf()` needs `"%s"` to know that it needs to print string. And then typecast items in vp[] to get rid of the warning given by `printf()` that you are passing incompatible pointer.

```
 printf("%s \n", (char *)vp[i])
```

Comment: And what happens if the data type of one group is different from `char*`?

Comment: Then you need one more varibale in the group telling what kind of data the pointers have.

Comment: Yes, and that's what the OP was asking.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot print values of arbitrary type in a general fashion. You could somehow store the type information and customize your `print` function, so that it supports all the possible types.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that this code snippet is in function main.

```
group *gp = (group*) malloc(sizeof(group));
void *a[2];
a[0] = (void*) "John";
a[1] = (void*) "Jim";
gp->data = a;
gp->count = 2;
```

and that you will access data members of the dynamically allocated structure while local array `void *a[2];` is alive.
Otherwise it would be better to allocate additional memory that would be pointed to by gp->data. For example

```
group *gp = (group*) malloc(sizeof(group));
gp->data = malloc( 2 * sizeof( void * ) );
gp->data[0] = "John";
gp->data[1] = "Jim";
gp->count = 2;
```

In this case that to output these data in some other function you need to know the actual type of pointer gp->data that to use an appropriate casting.

Thus if you know exactly that the actual type of data is `char **` then in some other function you can write

```
   for(i = 0; i < c; i++)
      printf( "%s\n", ( char * ) gp->data[i] );
```

Otherwise you need to enumerate all types that you are going to use with your structure and to add a corresponding data member that will be used in determination of the actual type of the pointer.